# Sharekit provides full facebook interface - but I just want a user post form!

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios4, sharekit

OK - I've got sharekit working well, but when I connect to facebook - the actual share page doesn't come up - just the full facebook mobile facebook site.

Anyone experience something similar? Do I need to call it differently?

I've tried this:

```
[SHKFacebook shareImage:imageView.image title:@"I found a trolley!"];
```

and I've tried this:

```
UIImage *image = imageView.image;
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem image:image title:@"I found a lost trolley!"];

[SHKFacebook shareItem:item];
```

What I really want is a "post to wall" share.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Kolya

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have everything set in `SHKConfig.h` file? I've been having few issues like this until I set the `SHKConfig.h` file properly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the development branch of [ShareKit/ShareKit](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/branches/development) which will then use [SHKFacebookForm](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/blob/development/Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/Facebook/SHKFacebookForm.h) to post item's of type `SHKShareTypeText`.